Approximation for the probability that each count in a multinomial distribution is at least 1
Suppose $(X_1, ..., X_m)$ follows a multinomial distribution with probabilities $p_i$ and $n>m$ draws. As per this answer, the probability that each $X_i$ is greater than $0$ is $$\sum_{A\subseteq [m]}(-1)^{|A|}\left(1-\sum_{k\in A}p_k\right)^n\;$$
But this probably has a lot of terms for even a medium-sized $m$. What is the best approximation to this that is reasonable to compute?

You are interested in computing $\Pr(\cap_{i = 1}^m {X_i > 0})$. You can lower bound it by upper bounding $\Pr(\cup_{i = 1}^m {X_i = 0}) \leq \sum_{i. =1}^m \Pr(X_i = 0) = \sum_{i = 1}^m (1- p_i)^n$. I am not sure if this works for your application.
